# Exception catch clause skipped for an error?

Tags: c#, oracle, try-catch

Something is fishy, and I know I must miss something.
I'm trying to connect to an Oracle instance, and due to firewalls, I cannot debug from my development machine.  So, for now I'm writing to the event log.
My ASP.net page displays "`Object reference not set to an instance of an object`", and I'm trying to find the error.

The comments in the code points to my funny issue.

Here is a code sample:

```
try
{
    OracleConnection oc = new OracleConnection(MyConnectionString);
    //Event log successfully created

    oc.Open();
    //Event log NOT created, thus error occurred in previous statement (I would assume)
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
  //Event log NOT created (?? - okay maybe there was no error)
}
finally
{
  //Event log successfully created
}
```

So it seems like the catch clause are not called, therefor I would assume no error.  But yet, I receive an error on the page.
The only other logical explanation is that the error occurs at the end of the finally clause or in the beginning of the catch clause, but the code to write the event log is the same as in the beginning.

So, what else can it be? Or perhaps, how else can I test it to find the error?

Comment: You have an issue with the log routine, try to log the same message twice in the try that you're saying it's ok (//Event log successfully created )

Comment: Maybe OracleConnection throws a non-CLSCompliant exception. If non-CLSCompliant exceptions is thrown then the catch (Exception ex) has no meaning. Try to catch the exception using an empty catch clause.

Comment: To OuSs comment: I made a duplicate message where you suggested, and it does create the message twice in the log.  Therefor I would assume the logging are correct.

Comment: To Yaniv: I made an empty catch clause.  Not no error are being displayed, but the same logs are still being written to the event viewer.  Thus the oc.Open does not run successfully, and the finally clause does execute.

Comment: OK, the catch clause now does write to the log, and I think my mistake came in that the ex.Message are empty.  It should write the ex.Message to the log, but the ex.Message is blank.  This should probably be a new post?  Is is possible for ex.Message to be empty?

Comment: Yep it seems like the problem was actually that Ex.Message was null and thus the error came from the logging.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem statement turned out to be that the logging in the catch clause produced the error because ex.Message was null.